# Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information). NEXT JS 14

Tags: npm, nextjs

me pasa algo muy extraño, estoy empezando a usar Next JS pero al inicializar un proyecto después de instalar dependencias, trato de levantar el servidor con npm run dev y me levanta la pagina pero unos segundos despues me aparece este error "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)." y en la consola de VS todo esto
Y SOLO ME FUNCIONA SI LEVANTO EL SERVIDOR CON "npm run dev -- --turbo", alguien sabe por que?

```
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/parse-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/add-path-prefix.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/add-base-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, ¿Que información tiene la consola del browser? `see the browser console for more information`